How to parse API JSON response that contains 1 list of multiple (2 in my case) types of objects in Android, I'm using Retrofit for API call
'So I searched enough, there isn't any question like this im sure. And I'm wondering how can this be not a questions others have come across or am I soo noob?
So the API response is as follow
{
"data": {
    "classId": "65d8376f8d58f95dd10c4e10",
    "name": "AI Fitness ",
    "displayName": "Fitness Lifestyle ",
    "rows": [
        {
            "type": "widget",
            "width": 0.6,
            "name": "test",
            "_id": "66793d57b935500b0b5090dc",
            "headerText": "Trending Globally ",
            "maxClickCount": 1000000,
            "cards": [
                {
                    "deepLink": "turnipgg://zaps/create?tab=cover&coverCategoryId=65d8444900677e37e4569aa9",
                    "imageUrl": "https://bulk-cover-dump.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/widgets/1_lovebirds.webp",
                },
                {
                    "deepLink": "turnipgg://zaps/create?tab=cover&coverCategoryId=65d8444900677e37e4569aac",
                    "imageUrl": "https://bulk-cover-dump.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/widgets/2_movies.webp",
                },
               
            ],
        },
        {
            "type": "cover",
            "width": 0.6,
            "_id": "65f43ef179f720000717c8be",
            "score": 18993,
            "name": "abcdef",
            "url": "https://overlays-prod.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/tlFPY89T.webp",
            "caption": "abc",
            "anonymous": false,
            "minimumTagCount": 0,
            "attributes": {
                "Guessable": false,
                "Hintable": false,
                "Anonymous": false
            },
        },
        {
            "type": "cover",
            "width": 0.6,
            "_id": "65f43ef179f720000717c8be",
            "score": 18993,
            "name": "abcdef",
            "url": "https://overlays-prod.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/tlFPY89T.webp",
            "caption": "abc",
            "anonymous": false,
            "minimumTagCount": 0,
            "attributes": {
                "Guessable": false,
                "Hintable": false,
                "Anonymous": false
            },
        },
        
    ],
    "nextToken": "eyJjIjoiMTIiLCJlIjoiIiwiZiI6IjEwIiwiciI6IiJ9"
}

}
and in this as you can see the key "rows" contains list of object but it has 2 different types of object in it, and based on the value of key "type" in each object, it can be either object of Type A or of Type B.
My Question :

Whats the best practice to parse this response in Android i'm using Kotlin and retrofit for network call. How should the data class look like.

My Current Solution:  I've only got 1 Data class which has keys of both the object in it, and based on the value of key "type" I distinguish between the two when mapping to your business objects.
Also ive read this article and also like the solution this guy used.
Great Article providing solution to exactly similar problem 
Question 2. Is my solution 1 ( having 1 data class which has keys of both the object)  better or solution 2 of (using gson custom type adapter better  which is what done in the above provided link)

GSON is really ancient reflection-based serializer and I would avoid it at all costs for Kotlin as it is not supported.
Kotlinx.serialization has built in polymorphism support and this can be done with simple @SerialName annotation to use type field as subclass serial name:
@Serializable
sealed class ApiData() {
   abstract val name : String

   @Serializable
   @SerialName("widget")
   data class Widget(override val name : String, maxClickCount: Int /*...*/) : ApiData()

   @Serializable
   @SerialName("cover")
   data class Cover(override val name : String, caption: String /*...*/) : ApiData()
}

That's it, you don't need any extra adapters here. Just register kotlinx.serialization as your preferred serializer for retrofit and you can parse your rows as List<ApiData>.

As much as this answer look interesting to me and i'm gonna go and read about Kotlinx.serialization , its built in polymorphism structure  and how exactly "Kotlinx.serialization has built in polymorphism support and this can be done with simple SerialName annotation to use type field as subclass serial name:"
If this answer works, lots of respect on your way Mr @Pawel. And will mark this as the accepted answer.

You can experiment with gson custom type adapter, where you can provide logic for mapping abstract data class to specific type (I have to admit that i do not test this solution properly with data, so keep this in mind :)).
First create your required data class structure:
(example)
abstract class AbstractClass(
    @SerializedName("name") open val name: String
)

data class ConcreteClass(
    @SerializedName("name") override val name: String,
    @SerializedName("additionalField") val additionalField: String
) : AbstractClass(name)

data class ConcreteClass2(
    @SerializedName("name") override val name: String,
    @SerializedName("additionalField2") val additionalField2: String
) : AbstractClass(name)


Second, create implementation of JsonDeserializer
(example)
class AbstractClassDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<AbstractClass> {

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): AbstractClass =
        when (json?.asJsonObject?.has("additionalField")) {
            true -> context!!.deserialize(json, ConcreteClass::class.java)
            else -> context!!.deserialize(json, ConcreteClass2::class.java)
        }
}

Third, provide gson instance with type adapter.
     GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(AbstractClass::class.java, AbstractClassDeserializer())
        .create()

then, when you provide this gson instance to your converter factory in retrofit and your return type from retrofit interface method has AbstractClass then custom deserializer should be used.

Great, thnx for such clean and detailed reply. I'm sure this is gonna help lot of other people coming to this question and in so many ways. Your solution works great, and i've applied such solution once before as well. Ive a followup question for you. What do you think, your solution is better or just having 1 Data class which has keys of both the object in it, and based on the value of key "type" we distinguish between the two when mapping it our business objects.?

can you explain a bit here what this guy is suggesting ?
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/retrofit-an-gson-deserialize-a-specific-object-type-based-on-the-value-of-a-field/10440/2
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/retrofit-an-gson-deserialize-a-specific-object-type-based-on-the-value-of-a-field/10440/3

this guy did exactly the same thing what Dawid is suggesting, I like it just not sure whats the best approct>?
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/retrofit-an-gson-deserialize-a-specific-object-type-based-on-the-value-of-a-field/10440/4

The approach that I have proposed will surely be more demanding and will require more code, but I personally think it is a 'cleaner' approach. This is because you do not need an additional Gson class with optional fields (that will never be used at the same time), so the structure is better represented with the type adapter approach.
However, if you are not coupled with gson, I would try kotlinx.serialization as @Pawel mentioned in his answer.
